# Trouble Passing Variable Info to First VC Using Closure

Tags: swift, variables, closures, viewcontroller, instantiation

I am trying to pass the data of which name was selected by the user in my `ShipViewController` to my `ProfileViewController`. I tried using closures to do so, but the title of the button in `ProfileViewController` (which presents the modal popover to `ShipViewController`) isn't changing to the name the user selects in `ShipViewController`.

Should it not be String --> () or is the way I instantiate my view controller incorrect?

```
(ShipViewController)

var completionHandler:((String) -> ())?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "shipCell", for: indexPath) as! ShipViewCell

    if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
        let result = completionHandler?(shipNames[selectedIndex!])
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

(In viewDidLoad of ProfileViewController)
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShipViewController") as! ShipViewController
    vc.completionHandler = { (text) -> ()in
        print(text)
        self.shipButton.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: Why are you dismissing in cellForItemAt indexPath instead of didSelect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dismiss `ShipViewController` in `didSelectItemAt`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let result = completionHandler?(shipNames[indexPath.item])
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In `ProfileViewController` Don't assign to completionHandler in `viewDidLoad`

Assign to completion handler in `prepare for segue`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showShip" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? ShipViewController {
             vc.completionHandler = { (text) -> ()in
                  print(text)
                  self.shipButton.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you presenting ShipViewController? Show that code

Comment: What do you mean by presenting the view controller? I have a popover that gets triggered when user clicks button but it's done through the storyboard.

Comment: Do you have identifier for the storyboard segue?

Comment: Yayyyy!! Thank you. Could you briefly explain why this works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190666/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-aza).